# How to request anonymously via Axios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, request, axios

I want to send a GET request to a url via axios.

It seems the website can recognize me via cookies and is redirecting the url to a page where logged in users are moved to.

**I want to send a request as if I were doing it from an incognito tab**

I have tried using `withCredentials: false` config.

This does not seem to have any effect with `true` or `false` in my case.

```js
 axios({
        url : url,
        method: 'get',
        maxRedirects: 15,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'text/html',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'GET',
        },
        withCredentials: false, // without cookies so no login
      })
      .then((res) => {
         console.log("Response", res.data)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
         console.log("Error with fetch: ", err)
      })
    });
```

Comment: which url you are trying to do this ?

Comment: @SaurabhMistry Its a Local one. But imagine it's something like the Facebook home page. If the user is logged in it shows something else and if not logged in it shows something else. (In my case it also redirects to a user page)

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to achieve this with axios. But found a way to do this with fetch api

I got the perfect output without previous cookies or login

```js
fetch(url, { 
        credentials: 'omit',
      }).then((response)=>{
        return response.text();
      }).then((data)=>{
        console.log(data);
      }).catch(err=>{
        console.log(err);
      })
```